# Chrome extension can't inject code on button press

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

My simple chrome extension doesn't work. Specifically, when I click the button in the popup, no alert is displayed.
Here is my manifest.json:

```
{"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["page.js"]}
```

And my popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<button onclick = "a()">Alert!!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

And my popup.js:

```
function a(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "page.js"});
}
```

Lastly, my page.js:

```
alert("Hi from an extension!!");
```

Yet no alert boxes come up. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Embedded js code doesn't work inside extension pages (the `onclick` code in your popup.html). Move it to a separate file and use e.g. [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). There should be an error shown in the popup's console, don't forget to always check it: rightclick the popup, then `Inspect`.
2. There's no need for `"<all_urls>"` because you're using [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab):

   > The activeTab permission gives an extension temporary access to the currently active tab when the user invokes the extension - for example by clicking its browser action. Access to the tab lasts until the tab is navigated or closed.
   >
   > This serves as an alternative for many uses of , but displays no warning message during installation.
3. `code` parameter of [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) expects a literal string with code, not a file name. Use `file` parameter.
4. `page.js` is a content script, it's not injected as a `<script>` element, but runs alongside in an ["isolated world"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment),
   so there's no need to declare it in "web_accessible_resources".

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. But why are inline event listeners blocked?

Comment: Because those are bad. See e.g. [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/a/5871775)